# MongoDB query based on last query by max date

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    consumerId: "...",
    dealId: "...",
    status: "...",
    stage: 0,
    createdDate: 2020-09-06T00:17:16.719+00:00
}
```

I would like to figure out how to get distinct documents given a specific `consumerId` and `status` not equal to say "x" or "y" based on the  latest `createdDate`. Also what would be the best indexes of fields for the collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$match` to apply the condition. `$sort` helps to do descending order of `createdDate`. Then groups helps to give the distinct data with the help of `$first`

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {$eq: ["$consumerId","1"]},
          {
            $not: {
              $in: ["$status",["x","y"]]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdDate: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$consumerId",
      consumerId: { $first: "$consumerId" },
      dealId: { $first: "$dealId" },
      status: { $first: "$status" },
      stage: { $first: "$stage" },
      createdDate: { $first: "$createdDate" }
    }
  }
]
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dhdNXpNTH0z)**

Comment: This helps me too, I was searching so far. @user2259183 why don't you accept the answer!! So that would help us